# canvas resizing and processingJS draw function not in-sync

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, processing.js

I made a game drawn on a canvas. The canvas background is blue. The draw function from processingJS is just drawing a light-blue background over the canvas.

The canvas takes up the whole window. That part is ok.
The canvas resizes to fit the window and I can see in the console that the window event listerner is working fine.

Ideally, I should see only light-blue. But I do not.

No matter what size the window, the screen is initially light-blue. If I resize to make it *smaller*, the window stays light-blue. If I make the window *bigger* than it was originally (when I refreshed the page), the remaining area of the window that is greater than the original size of the canvas is blue, instead of light-blue (meaning that the canvas is resizing, but the draw function is not drawing over all of it like I want).

Here is the css and html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
body, canvas, html {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:0 none;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
  background: rgb(100, 100, 255);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>    
  <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas> 
</body>
```

Here is the javacript code in a script tag.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/processing.js/1.4.8/processing.min.js"></script>

<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var canvasWidth = window.innerWidth;
var canvasHeight = window.innerHeight;
canvas.width = canvasWidth;
canvas.height = canvasHeight;

window.addEventListener("resize", canvasResize);

function canvasResize() {
  console.log("resize");
  canvasWidth = window.innerWidth;
  canvasHeight = window.innerHeight;
  canvas.width = canvasWidth;
  canvas.height = canvasHeight;
};

var sketchProc = function(processingInstance) {
with (processingInstance) {    
size(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
frameRate(30); 

//ProgramCodeGoesBelow

draw = function() {
  background(235, 245, 255);
};

//ProgramCodeGoesAbove

}};

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");    
var processingInstance = new Processing(myCanvas, sketchProc);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to link to a JSFiddle or a CodePen running your code? I can't seem to run your code by copy-pasting it.

Comment: I made a few changes. if you copy & paste it, it should work. I left out the link to the processingJS library the first time but I added that piece.

Comment: Also, I don't know really what JS fiddle is so I'm going to look into that because I get the feeling it may help me communicate my questions and so on.

Comment: Sorry, when I paste your code into CodePen I just see a light blue window. Yeah, JSFiddle and CodePen allow you to link to your code actually running, which is very helpful for these kinds of questions. You can also embed a runnable copy of your code directly into your post here on Stack Overflow, but I have less experience with that.

Comment: I tried doing it in JSfiddle and I see a light-blue square also. I don't know how to resize the 'window' in that program so that might make it hard to detect this peculiarity. I'm actually using notepad. When I copy and paste the above code into notepad, and run it in chrome, I start out with the light-blue box. But when I resize it bigger, I start seeing the darker-blue outlining the original light-blue box. But when I refresh, the whole thing goes light-blue again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is because even though you're resizing the canvas, Processing.js doesn't really know that you've resized the canvas. So it keeps using the original `width` and `height` values it calculated at the beginning of your program.

You can confirm this by adding this line to your `draw()` function:

```
text(width + " x " + height, 20, 20);
```

Those `width` and `height` variables are internal to your Processing sketch, and they don't change when you resize the canvas. After some tinkering, one solution that seems to work is to set those internal variables when you resize the canvas, like this:

```
function canvasResize() {
  console.log("resize");
  processingInstance.width = window.innerWidth;
  processingInstance.height = window.innerHeight;
  canvas.width = processingInstance.width;
  canvas.height = processingInstance.height;
};
```

Honestly that feels a little hackish so I wouldn't be surprised if you encounter other weird behaviors, but it seems to work for your example. Also note that you're using instance mode, so the code would look slightly different for a non-instance mode sketch.

Also note that Processing.js does give you access to the window size in the `screenWidth` and `screenHeight` variables, so you could change your `size()` function to this:

```
size(screenWidth, screenHeight);
```

That's not directly related to your problem, but it might save you a couple lines of code.

Comment: This is very exciting. I've made a few changes as you outlined to canvasResize and the result is just as I wanted. My programming skill is still modest so hackish though it may feel to someone more experienced, to me it looks super.